# using execv to use the './' command in linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, fork

I am building my own pseudo shell in linux.

I am using `execv` to run commands that could generally be done by the linux shell.

I have most commands working, but I do not know how to use `execv` with the './' command to run other programs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: `./` is not a command but a relative file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ isn't a command, it's a path to the current directory. It sounds like you should be using `execvp(file, argv)`, not `execv(path, argv)`.

Updated to add: just to be more specific, execvp does not search PATH if your filename contains '/'. This works, for example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    execvp("./hello.sh", NULL);
}
```

I have `hello.sh` in the current dir, compiled the code with `gcc test.c`, ran `./a.out` and it prints "hello world". '.' is not in my PATH.

Comment: `execvp` will search for `file` in the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable. It won't help at all if `file` is in the current directory and the current directory is not in `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, once I realized that ./ was not important to the command I just adjusted my string to only have the program name that came after it, and then the execv function worked perfectly.

Comment: Not if the filename contains a slash. Updated for clarity.

Comment: @bazzargh: '.' does not need to be in your PATH if your current directory is the one containing 'hello.sh'. The above would work with `execv` as well. Now try changing directory and running '/path/to/a.out'...

Comment: @isedev: he's asked for it to behave like a shell. ./ obviously means he wants to execute the thing in the current directory, not the directory where the binary is. Does my hello.sh need to be in /bin when I execute /bin/sh? execvp is the one that's defined to behave *like the shell* (ie, explicit file if specified, search the path otherwise) so it is clearly the one he wants, not execv.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Posix function: exec(3). You can see the manual at [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec).

One suggestion is remembering to check the return value of the exec(3). Most of time it won't work because the parameters you use is incorrect.

Comment: `exec` and `execv` provide the same functionality but with a different calling signature (former takes a variable number of `const char*` arguments, latter takes an array of `const char*`). Using `exec` won't help the OP.